# Invalid Signature for Google Calendar

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have read all the discussions here and have studied Google's APIs and OAuth spec, but I'm still getting an invalid signature.

I've tried using POST and GET, using Headers and Parameters, but still missing something. (Probably something easy or stupid.)

I have been successful using Hammock to retrieve a Request Token from Twitter so I'm perplexed as to what I'm leaving out for Google.

I'm writting this for Windows Phone 7 using VS 2010 Express and the Windows Phone 7 version of Hammock. Here is my code, please give me some advice.

```
    var requestTokenCredentials = OAuthCredentials.ForRequestToken("anonymous", "anonymous", "oob");

    var client = new RestClient();
    client.Authority = "https://www.google.com";
    client.Credentials = requestTokenCredentials; 
    client.HasElevatedPermissions = true;
    client.AddParameter("scope", GoogleURIs.myScope);

    var request = new RestRequest();
    request.Path = "/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken";
    client.BeginRequest(request, RequestCallback, client);
```

Richard

Comment: I'm stuck with a similar problem. Do let me know if you've found a solution.

Comment: I decided to use OAuth V2. Google recomends using the new version.  So far it has worked well for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research on Google OAuth APIs I decided to use OAuth V2. Google recomends using the new version and, so far, it has worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: Does Google's APIs require to send a valid referer ? Because I think it's not possible with the current version of the SDK to change the referer (but it will be with the Mango - 7.1 release as the beta only remove the bad referer i.e. the guid ID of the app when using the Image control for example).